# After Registration in XMPP User come OffLine in Openfire

Tags: ios, iphone, xmpp, xcode5, openfire

In my application i Successfully **Registered** the User in **openfire** from the use of **XMPP**.

but when i Registered the User for **first time** it is **coming offline**.
and I have to Connect it again.

**After disConnect** and connect again it is working Correct.

I don't know why this happen.

My Code is

```
-(void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender
{

NSLog(@"Did Connected pw:%@",_myTextViewCustom.text);
isOpen = YES;
NSError *error = nil;
[xmppStream authenticateWithPassword:_myTextViewCustom.text error:&error];

}
```

```
-(void)xmppStreamDidRegister:(XMPPStream *)sender
{

NSLog(@"xmppStreamDidRegister Method");

XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence];
[xmppStream sendElement:presence];


[xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@server_Id",_jidTextView.text]]];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![xmppStream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error])
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can't connect to server %@", [error localizedDescription]]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Connection is in making");

}


[self goOnline];

}
```

```
- (void)goOnline {
XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence];
[xmppStream sendElement:presence];
XMPPSystemInputActivityMonitor *activiyMonitor = [[XMPPSystemInputActivityMonitor alloc]init];
activiyMonitor.inactivityTimeInterval = 1;
[activiyMonitor addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
NSLog(@"Active : %d",[activiyMonitor isActive]);


UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Successfull!!!"
                                                    message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connected"]
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];


}
```

Any types of Help will be great.
Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue but not sure it's perfect or not so if you find another one then please tell me here.

i did change in

```
-(void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotAuthenticate:(DDXMLElement *)error
{
NSLog(@"didNotAuthenticate Method");

if(isRegister == TRUE)
{
    [xmppStream registerWithPassword:_myTextViewCustom.text error:nil];
    NSError * err = nil;

    if(![xmppStream registerWithPassword:_myTextViewCustom.text error:&err])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error registering: %@", err);

        [self performSelector:@selector(connect1) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];

    }

}
}  

-(void)connect1
{
isOpen = YES;
NSError *error = nil;
[xmppStream authenticateWithPassword:_myTextViewCustom.text error:&error];

}
```

I am calling Authentication again and it works but i don't think it's the final solution.

Comment: hey @sam it working fine or any new solution for it ..i  have same problem is going on ...can you help me on it.

Comment: yup...it's  working completely fine. if you find another good solution then let every one know here...

Answer (score 0):

Once registration done. You need to Authenticate your self to openfire server.

```
 [[self xmppStream] authenticateWithPassword:passwordString error:&error];
```

Once you call this method It will respond to

```
// get called on authenitcation successful 
- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender
```

and

```
//Error while authenticating 
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotAuthenticate:(NSXMLElement *)error
```

And then

```
[self goOnline];
```

Comment: thanks man for the answer but it's not working. i tried that but Connect method fire twice and i just want to did it with only one go. means when i registered the User He should be Online after Registration.

Comment: @Sam May be problem with your socket connection. Just check once socket coneection whether it connected or not after registration. And also send `available presence` to open fire server once registration done.

Comment: i tried this in socketDidConnect method but still no working. if you have any code you did in socketDidConnect method then please send me. so from that may be i'll get the solution. because registration is completed but user is still Offline first time.

Comment: @Sam There is no extra code needed. After calling `authenticateWithPassword` are you getting called authentication check (above) method. If not getting called then must be your socket disconnected and you are again connecting it. If still you are facing problem you can share NSLog so it may help to identify the problem.

Comment: Yes, i am getting problem in didNotAuthenticate method. from NSLog i got it. my code is passing from this condition 
        if(![xmppStream registerWithPassword:_myTextViewCustom.text error:&err])
        {
            NSLog(@"Error registering: %@", err);
            
        }
and i got the ERROR message in console is -Error Domain=XMPPStreamErrorDomain Code=1 "Please wait until the stream is connected." UserInfo=0x90bb4b0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Please wait until the stream is connected.}

Comment: Okay.. I have no idea about why xmppstream will give this error, may be xmppStream not established the socket connection. If you got idea just let me know also. To resolve this wait for 5 or more seconds then call `authenticateWithPassword` then it will work.

Comment: Okay i'll tell you when i'll find it but for now to call again **authenticateWithPassword** and **registerWithPassword** and **[xmppStream sendElement:presence];** is not giving me the result. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Don't call again `registerWithPassword' just call `authenticateWithPassword' method. It will work.